# Copying data from a shared-memory-mapped object using sendfile()/fcopyfile()

Tags: c++, posix, shared-memory, mmap, file-descriptor

Is it possible – and if so prudent – to use `sendfile()` (or its Darwin/BSD cousin `fcopyfile()`) to shuttle data directly between a shared-memory object and a file?

Functions like `sendfile()` and `fcopyfile()` can perform all of the mechanistic necessities underpinning such transfers of data entirely without leaving kernel-space – you pass along two open descriptors, a source and a destination, when calling these functions, and they take it from there.

Other means of copying data will invariably require one to manually maneuver across the boundary between kernel-space and user-space; such context-switches are inherently quite costly, performance-wise.

I can’t find anything definitive on the subject of using a shared-memory descriptor as an argument thusly: no articles for or against the practice; nothing in the respective `man`-pages; no tweets publicly considering `sendfile()`-ing shared-memory descriptors harmful; &c… But so, I am thinking I should be able to do something like this:

```cpp
char const* name = "/yo-dogg-i-heard-you-like-shm"; /// only one slash, at zero-index
int len = A_REASONABLE_POWER_OF_TWO;                /// valid per shm_open()
int descriptor = shm_open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);
int destination = open("/tmp/yodogg.block", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
void* memory = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, descriptor, 0);
off_t bytescopied = 0;
sendfile(destination, descriptor, &bytescopied, len);
/// --> insert other stuff with memset(…), memcopy(…) &c. here, possibly
munmap(memory, len);
close(descriptor); close(destination);
shm_unlink(name);
```

… Is this misguided, or a valid technique?

And if the latter, can one adjust the size of the in-memory shared map before copying the data?

---

EDIT: I am developing the project to which this inquiry pertains on macOS 10.12.4; I am aiming for it to work on Linux, with eventual FreeBSD interoperability.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @EJP I haven’t tried this exact scheme – the 3-hit combo punch of `shm_open()`, `mmap(…, MAP_SHARED, …)` and `sendfile()` – just yet, for two reasons. First, a minor point: I am right now developing natively on macOS, so my `sendfile()` is a polyfill using `fcopyfile()` … second: my current task is to implement access to a writeable files’ mapped memory through its wrapper class (which that wrapper already offers read-only memory maps, q.v. https://github.com/fish2000/libimread/blob/master/src/file.cpp#L115-L140); I will use what I learn doing that, and from SO, on the shared-memory problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying data between two "things" mapped in memory - like in the example above - will indeed require copying things from kernel to userspace and then back.  And no, you can't really use sendfile(2) system call to send to a file descriptor, I'm afraid.

But you should be able to do it like this:

1. Create the shared memory object (or a file, really; due to the second step it will be shared in memory anyway
2. Map it in memory, with MAP_SHARED; you'll get a pointer
3. Open the destination file
4. write(destination_fd, source_pointer, source_length)

In this case, the write syscall won't need to copy the data into your process.  Not sure what the actual performance characteristic will be, though.  Smart use of madvise(2) might help.

Comment: Good to know – and thanks for the tip about using `write(…)`. At first brush it seems that judicious use of both `madvise(…)` and `fadvise(…)` (with `FADV_SEQUENTIAL`) may be in order for optimal results, per the platform.